# Opening link in new tab if Check box is checked Otherwise opening it on same page

Tags: javascript, function, checkbox, onclick

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title> Untitled </title>
<script type="text/javascript">


function OpenWindow(info) {
    if
    {
  window.open(info,'WinName','height=400,width=600,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes');
    }
    else
    {
    target="_self";
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<p>
<input type="checkbox" name="CBox0" value="www.youtube.com" > Click To Open Link in New Window!</p>

<br>

<a href="http://www.youtube.com" target="new" id="y"onclick="if(this.checked){OpenWindow(this.value)}">Youtube</a>

</body>
</html>
```

This is what i have so far. When the check box is checked, if i click on a link, it will open the website up in a new tab. But if it is not checked, it opens up on the same page like a regular link. I have been working on this for awhile, so any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had some markup issues and inline stuff that I've removed. This should do it for you: http://jsfiddle.net/L47NY/7/

```
<input id="checky" type="checkbox">Click To Open Link in New Window</input>
<br />
<a href="http://www.youtube.com" id="linky">Youtube</a>
```

---

```
var checky = document.getElementById('checky');
var anchor = document.getElementById('linky');
var link = anchor.getAttribute('href');

function OpenWindow(href) {
    if (checky.checked) {
        window.open(href, '_blank');
    } else {
        window.open(href, '_self');
    }
}
anchor.onclick = function () {
    OpenWindow(link);
    return false;
};
```

Comment: It opens up in the current tab, but when i checked the box and click on the link, it doesnt open a new tab.

Comment: Hey @Travis, I made some updates - if you're checking in jsfiddle, keep in mind the frameset there will block the loading to '_self'. Best of luck!

Comment: If it's any consolation, my code earlier was really similar to that, andi was still having the same problems.

Comment: I do have the code in my actual file. I have my script function in my head and the input in the body tag. It doesnt open a new separate tab when the check box is checked. I dont understtand why. The code looks fine to me.

Comment: This code works without problems. Though you'll have to include it in an actual file and either add the javascript AFTER the markup (just before closing body tag), NOT in the head. Or place it in the head but call via window.onload.

Comment: Have you tried dropping the JS within script tags just before the closing body tag? I just want to make sure that it's not window.onload related.

Comment: I tried moving the script down to the body, still didnt work. My function window.onload is in the header in the script secion. is that correct>

Comment: You should be able to copy the script exactly as i have it in the answer into script tags just before the closing body tag:

<script>
    code code
</script>

It looks like you mixed some things up in the code you pasted into the comment, and there's a window.onload in there that's not needed.

Comment: Ahh thank you, It is working now. I am not sure what was going wrong. I didnt think anything was wrong with your code. Thank you a ton! :D

Answer (score 0):

You haven't actually told us the error you're getting.

In any case, your onclick statement should return true if you wish the click to proceed (behaviour varies per browser, but if you don't return true I know firefox won't open the link).

Also - you are checking if the ANCHOR tag is 'checked' when you say `this.checked`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a [simple example](http://jsbin.com/oFAmONe/16/edit?html,js,console,output) using jquery

```
$('#aLink').attr('target','_blank');

$('#chk').click(function(){
  if($(this).is(':checked')){
    $('#aLink').attr('target','_self');    
  }else{
    $('#aLink').attr('target','_blank');
  }
});
```

The only thing you need to do is to set the target property when the checkbox is or not checked.